# Getting SQL Error: ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month when running my statment

Tags: database, oracle

Guys not sure why I am getting the error in the title. See below, any help one the insert statement below would be much appreciated:

thanks in advance

```
INSERT INTO RUN_DATA VALUES ('15-JUL-18','5.00K','64:00','233','6','6','17.13','0')
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month
01847. 00000 -  "day of month must be between 1 and last day of month"
*Cause:    
*Action:


Name             Null Type         
---------------- ---- ------------ 
RUN_DATE              DATE         
RUN                   VARCHAR2(8)  
RUN_TIME              TIMESTAMP(6) 
CALORIES              NUMBER(4)    
SITUPS                NUMBER(3)    
PRESSUPS              NUMBER(3)    
WEIGHT                NUMBER(4,2)  
WEIGHT_LOSS_GAIN      NUMBER(2) 

PARAMETER                      VALUE                                                          
------------------------------ ----------------------------------------------------------------
NLS_DATE_FORMAT                DD-MON-RR                          

SYSDATE 
---------
21-JUL-18
```

Comment: Have you tried TO_DATE('15-JUL-18', 'DD-MON-YY')?

Comment: A standard date literal is like `date '2018-07-21'`. Anything else is either unnecessarily verbose or asking for trouble.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` for `RUN_TIME` instead of `TIMESTAMP`

Also, specify all the column names in the insert.

```
CREATE TABLE RUN_DATA (
RUN_DATE              DATE    ,     
RUN                   VARCHAR2(8) , 
RUN_TIME              INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND ,
CALORIES              NUMBER(4)    ,
SITUPS                NUMBER(3)    ,
PRESSUPS              NUMBER(3)    ,
WEIGHT                NUMBER(4,2)  ,
WEIGHT_LOSS_GAIN      NUMBER(2) 
  );

ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-RR'; --alternatively use DATE literal or TO_DATE


INSERT INTO run_data 
            (run_date, 
             run, 
             run_time, 
             calories, 
             situps, 
             pressups, 
             weight, 
             weight_loss_gain) 
VALUES      ('15-JUL-18', --or DATE '2018-07-15'
             '5.00K', 
             interval '64' minute,  --specifying proper interval
             233, 
             6, 
             6,      --quotes not needed for number types
             17.13, 
             0);
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7474a8)

Comment: Good suggestion to use INTERVAL  datatype to record the elapsed time, as that clearly fits the intent.

Answer (score 1):

Why working with Oracle you should learn two basic things.

1) do not rely on the table structure

2) do not rely on the session or database setting of DATE format

*Reason - both can easy be changed and your statement will fail.*

You violates both in your `INSERT` statement.

So try this

```
INSERT INTO RUN_DATA 
(RUN_DATE,RUN,RUN_TIME,CALORIES,SITUPS ,PRESSUPS,WEIGHT,WEIGHT_LOSS_GAIN)
VALUES (to_date('15.06.2018','dd.mm.yyyy'), -- define explicite DATE format
--- alternative use DATE literal  DATE'2018-06-15'
'5.00K',
TIMESTAMP '2018-01-31 09:26:50.124',   -- TIMESTAMP literal
'233','6','6','17.13','0')
```

Comment: Thanks for you help guys all sorted!!